# Can't type unbalanced closing curly brace in Clojure mode

Tags: balanced-parentheses, clojure, paredit

When I open a Clojure file, and I'm *not* using Paredit, I expect to be able to type unbalanced parentheses and brackets. I can type any of these characters: `()[]{`, balanced on not. But if I try to type a `}` that has no matching start `{`, it won't let me.

Why is this? And how do I turn it off? I expect this type of behavior in `paredit-mode`, but outside of that mode I want to be free to type any characters.

GNU Emacs 25.3.1 on macOS. Clojure mode 5.8.2.

Comment: Do you see this if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Emacs 27.0.50 and Clojure mode 20190105 from Melpa. It's possible it's a problem with the particular versions you're using, but more likely a problem in your init as @Drew suggests

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just noticed that it doesn't happen until I enable paredit-mode and then try to turn it off. So it seems like some remnant of paredit stays around and prevents the `}` character.

Answer (score 2):

The problem only occurs after you've turned `paredit` on and off: this is because `clojure-mode` adds a hook to `paredit-mode`, and that hook adds some `paredit-mode` keybindings to the `clojure-mode` map.

In other words, turning on `paredit-mode` makes changes to `clojure-mode` keybindings and those changes stick even if you turn off `paredit-mode`. The really surprising thing is if you edit a file in `clojure-mode`, then use `paredit-mode` in a different file, returning to the clojure file you'll get the paredit keybindings for "{" and "}".

That's arguably a bug in `clojure-mode`.

## Update:

This has been reported as a bug (not by me), although I'm not sure if the maintainer agrees:
https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/issues/504

Answer (score 1):

You can insert unbalanced parentheses with <kbd>C-q</kbd> (`quoted-insert`).

If you really don't want Clojure Mode to bind `{` and `}` to ParEdit keys, here is a work-around:

```el
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
          (lambda () (remove-hook 'paredit-mode-hook #'clojure-paredit-setup)))
```

(You need to restart Emacs, since once `clojure-paredit-setup` runs, the keys is set)