# Are there hooks for leaving modes?

Tags: hooks, major-mode, minor-mode

There seems to be a bug in `clojure-mode` (mentioned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46956/cant-type-unbalanced-closing-curly-brace-in-clojure-mode)) because it does things in a mode hook (for `paredit-mode`) but doesn't *undo* them when the mode is turned off.

I understand that `add-hook` can register a function to run when a mode is turned *on*, but is there a way to run a hook when a mode is turned *off*?

Here's a [github link](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/1ccef7b2b7a063aa42416d1518e8e7228d90a78d/clojure-mode.el#L553) see the `clojure-mode` code that adds the hook.

Comment: To further clarify, *minor* modes are entered and exited (and so hooks run on both occasions).  *Major* modes are never 'exited' at all, so they *cannot* run a hook before a different major mode is called.  Instead the new major mode effectively just clobbers all the buffer-local settings and starts over -- but the standard way that they do that means that `change-major-mode-hook` runs (with the original major mode still enabled), before anything else happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105 has more details about major modes and hooks, if you're interested.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the hook variable `change-major-mode-hook` for cleaning up major mode settings.
It is called right before killing the local variables of the old major mode.
Example code:

```el
(defun clojure-leave-clojure-mode-function ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'clojure-mode)
    (message "Leaving clojure-mode.")))

(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook #'clojure-leave-clojure-mode-function)
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but in general I think users shouldn't need to run any cleanup code manually, the major-mode should take care of this by making changes buffer locally.

Comment: @clemera If there is a bug in `clojure-mode` then that bug must be fixed. That is clear. Beside that take a look at the value of `change-major-mode-hook`. If you have `cc-mode` loaded then there is at least `c-leave-cc-mode-mode`. It is not so uncommon to use it for cleanup tasks.

Comment: Ok, but the major-mode should set it.

Answer (score 3):

Not for `major-modes`, for `minor-modes` the hook runs on exit as well (See [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47092/9198)). The major mode is responsible to make changes which affect other packages buffer locally. You probably should send a PR to change the `add-hook` code to install the hooks locally for the `clojure-mode` buffer:

```
(add-hook 'paredit-mode-hook #'clojure-paredit-setup nil 'local)
```

*EDIT*:

Looking at the code, this will not suffice. `clojure-paredit-setup` needs to be changed to do its changes buffer locally, too.

Comment: This won't solve the problem consistently, because `clojure-mode` adds the hook to `paredit-mode-hook` every time it runs. Your code removes the offending hook, but it will be replaced every time you open a new file in clojure-mode.

Comment: Hm, but  I suggested to add it buffer locally, the idea is that when activating `clojure-mode` it changes `paredit-mode-hook` only locally, for every buffer where it's activated. This way the global `paredit-mode-hook` is not effected, so there is nothing that need to be undone for non clojure buffers. BUT as I pointed out in the edit, `clojure-paredit-setup` needs to be changed, too because it changes other global variables.

Comment: Worth noting though, apparently that doesn't work if the buffer *(or emacsclient)* gets killed. So, if you want to undo something done when setting a minor mode up, apparently you need to come up with an ad-hock hack. The closest I've found to work is the `delete-frame-functions` hook.